# Creating 4 circles inside each other using css

Tags: html, css, geometry

I'm trying to get 4 circles within in each other (that don't have a background colour, just a border colour) with text inside the last one using CSS.

Example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SCYBw.jpg

Any idea on how this can be done?

Comment: Please read and apply the following instructions [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to your question! If you improve your question, you improve your chances for us to help you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make one circle inside of another using CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22406661/how-to-make-one-circle-inside-of-another-using-css)

Comment: you can draw those circles via a gradient, shadows or regular tags inbricated : http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/pPogKj no need to size it, use a pseudo to make the boxe a square and let it grow from the text.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you go. This should help you get started.

```css
.circle {
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: transparent;
  border: 2px solid red;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.c2 {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  border-color: blue;
}

.c3 {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border-color: yellow;
}

.c4 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="circles">

  <div class="circle c1">
    <div class="circle c2">
      <div class="circle c3">
        <div class="circle c4"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

It's a styling, so don't mess with inner HTML code. [CSS Gradients](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/radial-gradient) can do this well. it's even animatable

```css
 .container {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 12em;
  width: 12em;
  padding: 4em;
  text-align: center;
  background: radial-gradient(circle closest-side, 
   hsla(  0, 80%, 80%, 0) 0%, 
   
   hsla(  0, 80%, 80%, 0) 78%, 
   hsla(  0, 80%, 80%, 1) 79%, 
   hsla(  0, 80%, 80%, 1) 82%, 
   hsla(  0, 80%, 80%, 0) 83%,
   
   hsla(100, 80%, 80%, 0) 87%,
   hsla(100, 80%, 80%, 1) 88%,
   hsla(100, 80%, 80%, 0) 89%,
   
   hsla(200, 80%, 80%, 0) 92%,
   hsla(200, 80%, 80%, 1) 93%,
   hsla(200, 80%, 80%, 0) 94%,
   
   hsla(300, 80%, 80%, 0) 97%,
   hsla(300, 80%, 80%, 1) 98%,
   hsla(300, 80%, 80%, 0) 99%
  )
  ;
 }
```

```html
 <div class="container">
 My inner text is here
 </div>
```

Comment: This is the best answer for me because I want to avoid adding style-only HTML elements on a page. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Simply position all the circles on top of each other.

```css
 #outer-circle {
   border: 1px solid red;
   border-radius: 50%;
   height: 500px;
   width: 500px;
   position: relative;
   text-align: center;
 }
 #inner-circle {
   position: absolute;
   border: 1px solid red;
   border-radius: 50%;
   height: 480px;
   width: 480px;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   margin: -240px 0px 0px -240px;
 }
 #inner-circle2 {
   position: absolute;
   border: 1px solid red;
   border-radius: 50%;
   height: 460px;
   width: 460px;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   margin: -230px 0px 0px -230px;
 }
 #inner-circle3 {
   position: absolute;
   border: 1px solid red;
   border-radius: 50%;
   height: 440px;
   width: 440px;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   margin: -220px 0px 0px -220px;
 }
 #text {
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
   -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
   -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 }
```

```html
<div id="outer-circle">
  <div id="inner-circle">
    <div id="inner-circle2">
      <div id="inner-circle3">
         <div id="text">Breathe out</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my version.
My logic was divided into 2 steps:

- Step One : 
  The `.circle-1` is set as relative to be the container of the child's div.
- Step Two 
  The rest of the div's is set as absolute and has a smallest padding that their father, for their parent aways be bigger than the son.
  The align in x-axis is set by the `left` and `right` as `0` and `margin` as `0 auto`.
  The align in y-axis is set by the `top:50%` and `transform:translateY(-50%)`.

  ```css
  div{
    position: absolute;
    border: 3px solid;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    margin:0 auto;
  }
  .circle-1{
    top: 200px;
    padding: 40px;
    position: relative;
  }
  .circle-2{
    padding: 30px;
    border-color: blue;
  }
  .circle-3{
    padding: 20px;
  }
  .circle-4{
    padding: 10px;
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <div class="circle-1">
    <div class="circle-2">
      <div class="circle-3">
        <div class="circle-4"></div>
      </div>
    </div>  
  </div>
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Messing around with this as I procrastinated.

Vertically responsive, basic hover effect.

```css
html, body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: gray;
}
div {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.0);
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: white;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  padding: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 0.1s linear;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.ring1 {
  height: 100vh;
  width: calc(100vh);
}
.ring2 {
  border-color: royalblue;
}
.ring4 {
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-variant: small-caps;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: royalblue;
  background-color: salmon;
}
.ring1:hover, .ring1:hover div {
  padding: 3px;
  font-size: 32px;
  border-width: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="ring1">
  <div class="ring2">
    <div class="ring3">
      <div class="ring4">
        Breathe Out
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**fiddle**

https://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/9v4mLdep/