# How to create a circle inside a circle dynamically (like a donut)

Tags: html, css, user-interface

I want to create a circle inside a circle like a donut, but it should be create dynamically. for eg. If I have a page width 500px and height 500px, it should fit. 
or if I have some other width and height like 100px and 100px, it should fit in. I am creating a component in angular project using div and css. 
I have gone through the below URL, but there the height and width are fixed
[How to make one circle inside of another using CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22406661/how-to-make-one-circle-inside-of-another-using-css)

Below is the css for inner and outer circle

```
.empty-wheel-outer {
  display: inline-block;
  width:  60px;
  height: 60px;
  border: 1px solid $alto;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.empty-wheel-inner {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  border: 1px solid $alto;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 13px;
}
```

Comment: instead of using fixed sizes set height and width to `100%` or `100vw/vh`

Comment: This question meets the requirements for posting, if you're going to downvote please explain why.

Comment: @NibblyPig. Not really. There isn't even any HTML included. We have to make assumptions about OPs code.

Comment: using height and width to 100% solves my issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

height and width will be added dynamically for child items in % and it will be centered automatically by adding circle class

`Try changing child width and height it will stay in center`

Ping me if you  need further explanation.

```css
.wraper {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
}

.circle {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.empty-wheel-outer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.empty-wheel-inner {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wraper">
    <span class="circle empty-wheel-outer">
      <span class=" circle empty-wheel-inner"></span>
    </span>
    <div/>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

This should help:

```css
.outerCircle{
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-radius: 50%; 
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.innerCircle{
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="outerCircle">
  <div class="innerCircle"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, a lot, It worked smoothly with flex usage and providing 100% as height and width. using percentages, it occupy the space of parent div height and width

Answer (score -1):

I made some changes in your code. Please check this

[Answer to "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54881664/how-to-create-a-circle-inside-a-circle-dynamically-like-a-donut"](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eXYXQb)

CSS :

```css
.empty-wheel-outer {
  display: inline-block;
  width:  -webkit-fill-available;
  height:  -webkit-fill-available;
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.empty-wheel-inner {
      display: inline-block;
    width: -webkit-fill-available;
    height: -webkit-fill-available;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin: 0 10%;
}
```

```html
<div class="empty-wheel-outer">
  <div class="empty-wheel-inner">
  </div>
</div>
```